# Issue reading an excel sheet in python 3 using XLRD

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an issue reading an excel sheet in python 3. I am using the python library "xlrd". **And all data is in "text" data type in the excel sheet**.

Issue: It reads few cell values in a different way than what actually is there in the cell.

For example:
These are few rows from the excel file named "All_TPN_SearchResults.xlsx" which I am trying to read:

```
42398 010277    RES,1.15K,MF,RN55D,1%   HEAVY & HIGHWAY|GENERAL INSTALL PARTS 2D
42399 010284    TUBING,SHRINKABLE BL    CORP,MANUFACTURING|MISCELLANEOUS
42400 010284    TUBING,SHRINKABLE BL    CORP,MANUFACTURING|MISCELLANEOUS
```

**Where 42398, 42399, 42400 are the row numbers from excel file** and rest are actual data. Here is the image of that data sample: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB7ER.png

The code which I am running is:`

```
import xlrd
file_location = "All_TPN_SearchResults.xlsx"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
print(sheet.cell(42399,0).value)
```

The output of the code:
    10284

The expected output of the code:
    010284

Can somebody shed some light on what the problem is?

Note: It's my first time at Stack exchange and English is not my native language. So, I may not have put my problem in a perfect way, but, I have tried my best to be as descriptive as possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience! I have edited my post now. Hope this helps.

Comment: No need to be sorry; your question is much better now! To me, it looks like you need to force interpretation of the second field as text or string rather than a number. Otherwise, I can't really help you much.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is exactly what you are looking for :

["xlrd force read number as text"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-excel/GMZMQu1NZt8)

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But, I think, the link you have shared explains the same thing if the "data type" of the column was "number". But in my case, the "data type" of the column is "text". Plus the parameter "formatting_info=True" which is talked about in the discussion is still not implemented. I hope you understand! If not, sorry for mine English! Do you have any other material for my reference?